# Store logging in separate or existing database?

Tags: sql-server, storage

In a .NET WebForms project we want to log certain actions in a database for a year. The estimate is that the log will have a maximum size of 1GB (20.000 records per day of 10 fields) that will probably be queried a maximum times of 2 per day.

We are discussing if it is advisable to put the logging table in a new database (on perhaps even a separate server), or use a new table in our existing database.

The advantages of using our existing database are that we do not need to make a new connection in the code nor administrate a new database. The disadvantage might be that the database cannot handle it.

What are your insights? Do you have any advice?

Comment: Please dont consider this as expert advise as it would require few more information to give good answer but a 1G table in a database is not a bad idead depends on how much loaded database is I/O contentions etc. You can have new logging table in database I have seen lots of environments with what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I wouldn't be too worried about which database the log goes in (at least for performance reasons); same or different database can have a filegroup on same or different physical files, and these can be moved if you need to spread I/O out in either case. What I would worry about is once data is a year old, what is your strategy to purge/archive? I would rather do small chunks frequently than deleting a week or month at a time. [Some info here](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/03/io-subsystem/chunk-deletes).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would go for the same database, for the reasons you state in your question. If you're worried about performance or growth, create a new "logging" filegroup and put the logging table(s) on that. If things grow out of hand in the future, you can move the .ndf (the physical file that contains the new filegroup) to a different physical drive.

Even if you stick to the same server and add a new database, the effect is similar. You don't have to create a new connection in your client application - all you have to do is reference the table by a three-part name, [database].[schema].[table].

Edit: also, consider if the logged information should "follow" the rest of the database, or if it's specific to a certain server or environment.

Comment: Choice of the same database is becked up by the load: 20000 records per day, assuming a work day of 8 hours, is slightly less than 1 record per second, which isn't very much at all these days.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean with "Following" the rest of the database?

Comment: If you have multiple instances of your database, like dev, test and production, you need to decide if the logs are relevant only for each instance, or if the logs are "global".